# I am trying to sort my data in mongoose database and with find() function I am getting my output but I want to sort my data with paginate() function

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose, pagination

**JS**

As you see I am trying to sort my data with paginate function but I get an error message

```
let records = await modelVendor.paginate ({ },{limit ,page}).sort({"rating":  json.rating });
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I solve my error.

```
let records = await modelVendor.paginate({},{limit,page , sort : {"rating": json.rating}});
```